# on_ready event triggers on_guild_remove message

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So,for some days,when my bot gets online,it triggers the on_guild_remove message(the message just sends on my server when the bot leaves a server),instead of name it says "None" and the ID is always the same

any way I can fix this problem?

my on_ready and on_guild_remove code is:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    try:
        client.loop.create_task(status_task())
        print('Hellooo! Detective')
        timestamp = datetime.now()
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title="I am now Online!", description=timestamp.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S %p"), color=0xe74c3c)
        channel = client.get_channel(864074870441639936)
        await channel.send(embed=embedVar)       
    except Exception as ex:
       print(f"Error found: {ex}")

@client.event
async def on_guild_remove(guild):
  embedleave = discord.Embed(title="Left a server", description=f"just left {guild.name}\n{str(len(client.guilds))}", color=0x71368a)
  embedleave.set_footer (text =f"{guild.id}")
  channel = client.get_channel(865213199917908016)
  await channel.send(embed=embedleave)
  
  with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
    prefixes = json.load(f)

  prefixes.pop(str(guild.id))

  with open('prefixes.json','w') as f:
    json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)
```

Comment: Wdym by "the ID is always the same"? That shouldn't happen, is it because you been testing by leaving the same guild?

Comment: No,i havent tested that thing,for a good amount of time it was going well,out of no where it started doing that,when the bot leaves/joins a server it has the server id in the message

Comment: Maybe someone's been inviting and kicking your bot in their server for some strange reason? I don't believe the ID issue is reproducible. Could you try testing the issue by creating a testing server, invite the bot and kick the bot and see if your issue is present.

Comment: no,there is no join message,the messages work fine beside that bug,i test it,it only the on ready event that triggers that message